# Run function when the text inside a div changes

Tags: javascript

I need to add an event listener to all divs with a specific class name.
I coded the following eventlistener, but then realised that it won't work because as far as I can tell the Onchange event only works for form elements?

How can I detect when text inside a any div with a specific class name changes? Then I want to run a function.

```
var myLinkList = document.querySelectorAll(".my-link");
myLinkList.forEach(myLink => {
    myLink.addEventListener('change', event => {
        createSummary()
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a MutationObserver to each such element:

```js
for (const link of document.querySelectorAll(".my-link")) {
  new MutationObserver(() => {
    console.log('Link changed to:', link);
  })
    .observe(link, { childList: true });
}

setTimeout(() => {
  document.querySelector('.my-link').textContent = 'something else';
}, 2000);
```

```html
<div class="my-link">foo</div>
<div class="my-link">bar</div>
```